# Dryer Current Requirements for wiring & breakers

Tags: dryer

A specific [washer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Samsung-7-5-cu-ft-Stackable-Vented-Electric-Dryer-with-Sensor-Dry-in-White-DVE45T6000W/313846237) and [dryer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Samsung-4-5-cu-ft-High-Efficiency-Front-Load-Washer-with-Self-Clean-in-White-WF45T6000AW/313846213) pair are to be installed into a utility room that has an electric water heater and fusebox.  Washer = 120V Dryer:  240V

The dryer is a Samsung WF45T6000AW.  It is my understanding that most 240V dryers require 30A: 10 Ga wire.

The [user manual is found here](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/3a/3a2f20cb-03f5-4442-9e94-3fa97fdeeb65.pdf)

The [installation Guide is found here](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/ef/efdc13eb-d7d3-4d07-b748-d906b97ee24f.pdf)

The [specification Guide is found here](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/10/105c0b74-3864-4157-b60c-936ea6af23e2.pdf)

I am unable to find any documentation that provides the Ampere (electric current) requirement at 240V.  I sense that it is necessary to understand the Ampere requirement: how do I find this information on the internet?

Comment: There’s no dryer info in the linked docs because you’ve linked to the washer documents.

Comment: @nobody  Links are updated to point to the dryer.  Thank you for catching the error and quoting the 30 Ampere requirement on pp.20.  of the [dryer user manual](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/3a/3a2f20cb-03f5-4442-9e94-3fa97fdeeb65.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pp. 20 of the [dryer manual](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/3a/3a2f20cb-03f5-4442-9e94-3fa97fdeeb65.pdf) says:

> A 30-ampere fuse or circuit breaker on both sides of the line is required.

This document is linked from the dryer product page (which you have mistakenly labeled as the washer in your question).

Answer (score 2):

You will need a 30A 2-pole breaker, 4-wire (10/3 w/ground) cable to a NEMA 14-30 receptacle.

When installing the 4-wire cable on the dryer, follow the instructions carefully, as the neutral-ground bootleg jumper must be disconnected and stowed.

If the washer has existing legacy 120V 15A circuit it can use, that is fine.  However it will hog the entire circuit.

If you are adding a circuit for the washer it must be 20A and use #12 wire or cable.

Since this is an addition, you must re-do the house's Load Calculation according to NEC Article 220, to assure you have the service needed for the new circuit(s).

The dryer circuit will require 5500 VA in the Load Calculation.  A new washer circuit would require 1500 VA.   Depending on the formula used, this may be subject to a favorable adjustment.